# How to install apt-get on Ubuntu Mate

Tags: raspberry-pi, ubuntu-mate

I think I accidentally removed my `apt-get` and I am getting the error as follows:

```
sudo apt-get command not found
```

Comment: Welcome to U&L. This is because you haven't told it what to do. Basically you have said to do something, but you need to specify what you want; i.e. `apt-get update` or `apt-get upgrade`, etc. Have a look at what you can do with `apt-get` on Google.

Comment: @Kevdog777 thank you soo much it worked !!

Answer (score 2):

Download the `.deb` package then install it using `dpkg` , e,g ([Ubuntu Xenial](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/armhf/apt)):

```
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/360031361/apt_1.2.26_armhf.deb
sudo dpkg -i apt_1.2.26_armhf.deb
sudo apt update
```